# How to parse date string in jQuery and check if it is in the past

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I need to check if the date is in the past. This is what I have so far. [JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bts9b/).

```
var date = "09/12/2013";
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var todaysDate = +(('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + d.getFullYear();

if (date < todaysDate) {
    alert("in the past");
} else {
    alert("in the future");
}
```

Currently it is saying that the date was in the past, when it should be in the future. I know I need to parse the string as a date, but not sure how.

Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With that input format, you can't use a string comparison, because the least significant values are on the left. **Note**: I'm assuing that date is December 9th, 2013. If you're doing the American thing where it's September 12th, 2013, you'll have to adjust the indexes into `parts` below.

You *could* reverse the fields:

```
var date = "09/12/2013";
var parts = date.split('/');
date = parts[2] + "/" + parts[1] + "/" + parts[0];
```

...and then do your string comparison (being sure to construct the string for "today" in the same order — year/month/day).

If you're going to do that, you could go ahead and finish the job

```
var date = "09/12/2013";
var parts = date.split('/');
var date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10),     // year
                    parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, // month, starts with 0
                    parseInt(parts[0], 10));    // day
if (date < new Date()) {
    // It's in the past, including one millisecond ago
}
```

...but of course, if you don't want the expression to be true for one millisecond ago, your string approach is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date("09/12/2013");
var d = new Date();
console.log(date>d); // true
var date = new Date("09/12/2011");
console.log(date>d); // false
```

Comment: That date format is not reliably converted on all browsers. In fact, it can't be reliably converted by all people, either. Is the date in December, or September?

Comment: This works, though the date format will vary with locale. Personally, I used a date like `var date = new Date("2012-10-31T00:00:00+13:00");` and it works fine. Nice simple solution thanks.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript's native Date comparator only works on Date objects, whereas you are comparing Strings. You should parse `date` into a `Date` object, and then compare it with `d`.

```
//define parse(string) --> Date
if(parse(date) < new Date()) {
  alert('past');
} else {
  alert('future');
}
```